# Jhipster and Angular 6: Save an entity with another page than the generated entity page

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

im quite new to Angular 6, before I worked with AngularJS and now I'm struggling with an issue.

I generated an app with Jhipster with which I would like to do online assessments. Therefore I generated a form for doing the assessments (figure 1) and an entity called "assessment" with which I would like to store and manage all assessments. Now I would like to use the assessment-object that is provided by the entity "assessment", fill it with the data from the form and save it with the (from jhipster) auto-generated function for storing an entity in the database. The form is located in the do-assessment package.

My problem is now, that I'm not able to

1) use the object from the assessment-entity class
2) call the function from the assessment-update.component.ts

how, in general, is it possible to achieve something like this?

thanks and best regards,
Alex

[image: assessment form]
[image: project structure]

Comment: Your question is rather vague: what have you tried and what are the problems you are facing? Have you imported the classes and injected the service into your component?

Comment: thanks for fast reply and sorry for my late reply. I figured it out on my own and my problem was that i didn't understand the changed concept of Angular. The problem really was that I did not injected the needed classes correctly.